# ionic2 native map multiple markers

Tags: cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2, phonegap-gmaps-plugin

I'm trying to implement native google maps in my ionic 2 project but i get an error to set markers clickable. 
this is my code to draw markers:

```
for (var i = 0; i < mapMarkers.length; i++) {
                var centerMarker = mapMarkers[i];
                 let location = new GoogleMapsLatLng(centerMarker.lat, centerMarker.long);
                let MarkerDetails = centerMarker.name ;
                let markerOptions = {
                  position: location, title: MarkerDetails ,snippet:centerMarker.distance , icon:this._MapService.markerImg
               };
     this.map.addMarker(markerOptions)
                  .then( (marker: GoogleMapsMarker) => {
                    console.log('centerMarker.ID'+centerMarker.ID)
                     marker.addEventListener(GoogleMapsEvent.INFO_CLICK).subscribe(
                        ()=>{
                            this.navToCenter(centerMarker.ID);
                        }
                    );
                });
            }
```

it appears on the map but my problem here is

```
this.navToCenter(centerMarker.ID);
```

always go to the last marker.

I'm using GoogleMap class from ionic-native to create the map as on documentation here : 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/google-maps/
also i know that the problem because of promises like the description on plugin documentation 
https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/Marker#create-multiple-markers

I need any way to handle this solution using ionic2 GoogleMap class & Typescript.
regards.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41099774/ionic-2-google-maps-marker-click-event practically the same question..

Comment: thanks @SurajRao you saved my day